# How to handle camera interruption states in iOS application using Vuforia for augmented reality same asARKit?

Tags: ios, augmented-reality, vuforia, xcode9, arkit

In one of my application am using **Vuforia** and **ARkit** for loading 3dimages in camera mode. I have to detect camera interruption states and need to display alert to load camera screen with new images.
In ARKit we have delegate methods

```
- (void)sessionWasInterrupted:(ARSession *)session;
```

Is there any delegates in **vuforia SDK** to detect session interruption.

Following are the scenarios to be handled

Scenario 1: 
User opened ARViewcontroller using vuforia and 3dmodel has been loaded and immediately pressed home screen.
When user again opens the app I have to dismiss the ARView and neew to show alert that session has bee interupted please start new session.

Solution:
I tried to handle this scenario using Appdelegate Methods.applicatonDidEnterBackground.

Scenario 2 :
User opened ARViewcontroller using vuforia and 3dmodel has been loaded and immediately pressed home screen.
Now user pressed lock/Power button.
In this mode App still in foreground.
How to handle this case. Need any suggestions/solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem using Appdelegate methods

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

along with **NSNotificationCenter**